# Test email sending with no controller

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, email, swiftmailer

My application sends many emails. The official doc tells [how to test emails sending](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html) with the HTTP client profiler.

But I obviously don't have a Controller for each email I'm sending.

How can I test my emails that are not triggered from a controller ? (I mean not from a request context).

---

**Further detail on my specific case**

I'm using a listener to trigger calls to a service which is doing the "email routing"
What I'd like to do here, is fire some events and check what is sent (the email body, title, recipients, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this [great post](https://www.pmg.com/blog/integration-testing-swift-mailer/) I extended the `Swift_MemorySpool`

```
class CountableMemorySpool extends \Swift_MemorySpool implements \Countable
{
    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->messages);
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }
}
```

Passed it to the mailer used by my service

```
class MailServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    protected $mailService;
    protected $spool;
// ...
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->spool = new CountableMemorySpool();
        $transport = new \Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport(
            new \Swift_Events_SimpleEventDispatcher(),
            $this->spool
        );
        $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
        $this->mailService->setMailer($mailer);
    }
```

And tested

```
    // ...
    public function testMailSpec()
    {
        // ... Sending the mail ...
        $this->assertCount(1, $this->spool,
            'Expected exactly one email to be sent');
        $msg = $this->spool->getMessages()[0];
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('tartempion@test.com', $msg->getTo(),
            'Wrong recipient');
        $this->assertContains('Tartempion', $msg->getBody(),
            'Expected some string contained in the email body');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the article you're linking at is about functional (e2e) testing, not the unit.

Second, for unit-testing you need to inject some MailerMocker in your Listener (which sends emails) instead of real Mailer.

For example, you may create a simple Mocker like this

```
class SwiftMailerTester extends \Swift_Mailer
{

    /**
     * @var array[\Swift_Mime_Message]
     *
     */

    protected $sentMessages = array ();

    /**
     * @var \Swift_Mime_Message
     */

    protected $lastSentMessage;

    public function __construct() {

    }
    /**
     * Mocks sending message
     *
     * @param \Swift_Mime_Message $message
     * @param null                $failedRecepients
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function send(\Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecepients = null)
    {

        $this->lastSentMessage = $message;
        $this->sentMessages[] = $message;

        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * @return array[\Swift_Mime_Message]
     */
    public function getSentMessages()
    {
        return $this->sentMessages;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Swift_Mime_Message
     */

    public function getLastSentMessage()
    {
        return $this->lastSentMessage;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSentMessagesCount()
    {
        return count($this->sentMessages);
    }
}
```

And then in your unit test access lastSentMessage (or sentMessages) to analyze if Listener had done it's work right.

Comment: Thank you this is interesting. I'm actually working on a technique based on the memory spool extension, that I'm going to put as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into setting up the [global request context](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html) which, although the documentation is for Commands, should help with your situation unless you can provide further, specific, information.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the detail about my specific case. I'd like to avoid any request context as my emails are sent 95% without.